# Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application BUT In WEB LOGIC

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, weblogic, static-content

I found answer here,
[Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java/1812356#1812356)

it is excellent solution and working fine in my case also.

But my application is deployed on web logic.

I tried to get same file server.xml in like we do have in $cataline/config/server , but i think there must be different file of WebLogic

so, above same setup, i need to do for our application deployed on WebLogic.

Comment: maybe duplicate of [How to serve static resources using Spring's mvc:resources on WebLogic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038834/how-to-serve-static-resources-using-springs-mvcresources-on-weblogic) but I can't flag it as there's no accepted answer. Please check.

Comment: Looking answer for WebLogic, given solution works only with tomcat.

Comment: I didn't test and don't have the material for this, but the answer is referring to `wls` tags which clearly are for Weblogic.

Comment: finally i found this solution, not available on stackoverflow.  <weblogic-web-app>

<container-descriptor>
<index-directory-enabled>true</index-directory-enabled>
</container-descriptor>

<virtual-directory-mapping>
     <local-path>C:\Oracle\Middleware\</local-path>
     <url-pattern>Oracle_Home/*</url-pattern>
  </virtual-directory-mapping>
  
  <virtual-directory-mapping>
     <local-path>C:\</local-path>
     <url-pattern>softwares/*</url-pattern>
   </virtual-directory-mapping>

<context-root>/filedrive</context-root>

</weblogic-web-app>

Comment: Thanks for sharing. If it's working, please add your solution as an answer, it might help people.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found following answer. Not available on stackoverflow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app>
<container-descriptor>
<index-directory-enabled>true</index-directory-enabled>
</container-descriptor>
<virtual-directory-mapping>
 <local-path>C:\Oracle\Middleware\</local-path>
<url-pattern>Oracle_Home/*</url-pattern>
</virtual-directory-mapping>
<virtual-directory-mapping>
<local-path>C:\</local-path>
<url-pattern>softwares/*</url-pattern>
</virtual-directory-mapping>
<context-root>/filedrive</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```